Books which expound on Divine Tradition and the Catholic Church
In 1928, Tradition and the Church by Msgr. George Agius, DD, JCD was published.
In 2005, the TAN Publishers revised it somewhat, adding, among other things, a Publisher's Preface, and republished it. In that preface, one reads on p. xiv:

The only book in English we know of that discusses the nature of Tradition, Tradition and the Catholic Church covers most aspects of the nature of Catholic Tradition, and will be a font of tremendous understanding about the sources of our Faith ...

QUESTION: Does anyone know of any other Catholic books besides the above that were either written in or translated into English which address in depth, Divine Tradition and the Church?

Fr. Chad Ripperger, Topics on Tradition (2013) and The Binding Force of Tradition (2013)

Oddly enough, on the back cover of the 2005 TAN edition of "Tradition and the Church," Fr. Ripperger writes: ```Tradition and the Church' is the only book I know of that gives a profound understanding of exactly what Catholic Tradition is...."

I see the books you cite by Ripperger are both (2013); perhaps, that explains it.

@DDS Explains what?

Why Fr. Ripperger's alluded to comment appears on the TAN Book. He didn't publish the two little books (pamphlets with covers?) until 8 years later. The first you mentioned appears to me to be a reprint of three articles the author published in a journal of some sort. As the questions asks, I am trying to find out if anything (in depth) has been published in addition to Fr. Agius' book---which to the best of Fr. Ripperger's knowledge---the answer would seem to be no. Thank you for pointing out these two publications of his. I expect them to be useful.
